# Как в IDEA вернуть закрытую вкладку с логами

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Запускаю проект, во вкладке `RUN` вижу вкладки для `console` и `log`. Случайно закрываю `log` и не понимаю как её вернуть без перезапуска проекта.

Есть ли какие-то хоткеи для этого?

Скрин с табом, который нужно вернуть после закрытия оного:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Немного подробностей:

Это `Java`, `Servlet`. Использую `Gradle`, команду `appStartWar`, в её конфиге, во вкладке `Logs` указал путь к файлу куда `log4j2` пишет логи. Именно они во вкладке `log` выводятся и которую мне хочется иметь возможность открывать после закрытия.

**UPD**

Завёл багу на сайте производителя IDE: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170540

Comment: попробуйте указать тип проекта

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, боюсь, что я не понял что вы имеете в виду... Тип запускаемого мной проекта? Это Java, Servlet. Использую Gradle, команду `appStartWar`, в её конфиге, во вкладке `Logs` указал путь к файлу куда `log4j2` пишет логи. Именно они во вкладке `log` выводятся и которую мне хочется иметь возможность открывать после закрытия.

Comment: В конце линии вкладок должна быть кнопка "Restore log view"

Comment: @vp_arth, у меня эта кнопка слева, 3-я сверху и она ничего не делает( Вот в AndroidStudio при закрытии `logCat` справа кнопка появляется и работает, а `IDEA` нет(

Comment: Ну да есть такой неприятный баг/фича в Idea - сам бы с удовольствием подсмотрел как народ ее решает. Я то решаю ее по сермяжному: открываю пустой проект, там вкладка логов всегда есть и просто перетаскиваю ее оттуда в свой проект

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Разрешите уточнить, какие метки по вашему считаются "не популярными" и зачем их надо удалять? Метка `ide`, например, действительно усложняла поиск этого вопроса?

Comment: @0xdb Я бы не сказал, что усложняет, но она действительно как минимум за год с момента этого вопроса так и не развилась в метку с приличным количеством подписчиков и вопросов

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Метка должна упрощать поиск конкретного вопроса. Сколько под нею уже других вопросов и подписчиков второстепенно. Может я утрирую, но есть очень специальные темы, у которых возможно будет 0 подписчиков и несколько вопросов. После удаления метки из вопроса, он возможно будет вообще больше не найден.

Comment: @0xdb Тогда зачем такие метки где 0 подписчиков и несколько вопросов ?! А про то что ваш вопрос не найдут, не парьтесь!! Я просмотрел много вопросов по Java и пришел к выводу, что когда вопрос касается intellij-idea, то в основном так и пишут в метках не обобщая до метки ide!

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Почитайте тему [метки в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). "А про то что ваш вопрос не найдут" - какой мой вопрос не найдут?

Comment: @0xdb Немного не так выразился, извиняюсь! Вы писали: " После удаления метки из вопроса, он возможно будет вообще больше не найден."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Детально как дойти к нужному:

[image: опции логирования]

Если все настроено правильно то вы сможете видеть все логи в виде вкладок, примерно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[!] Важно: если вы закрыли вкладку лога и в опциях напротив этого лога установлена галочка то для его повторного отображения в виде вкладки необходим перезапуск вашего приложения (можно закрыть все вкладки логов которые у меня на скрине и они повторно будут отображены ТОЛЬКО после перезапуска как было отвечено выше и никак иначе),
галочки после закрытия вкладки не снимаются сами по себе.

-- ок, если ни 1 из вариантов не подходит то:
1)  вы можете добавить сам лог файл прямо в Editor и просматривать его содержимое там - перетащите файл прямо на панель Editor'a (проверьте кодировку - если что-то не так то Идея сама предложит возможные кодировки)
2) Для Editor в Keymap есть возможность переоткрывать закрытые вкладки на случай если вы ее закрыли, для консольных вкладок такого компонента в моей версии Идеи нет (2016.5.2 - в младших тоже не встречал) - нужно только назначить комбинацию тут: "File - Settings - Keymap" - найти "Editor Tabs" - "Reopen Closed Tabs".

Comment: Ну, в этом мы уже разобрались. Вопрос в поиске способа переоткрывать вкладку лога без пересборки/перезапуска приложения. Судя по тому, что эти вкладки имеют смысл вообще без запущенного приложения(фильтры файла логов) - я склонен считать это багом, требующим фикса...

Comment: дописал как можно выйти из ситуации, + в самом Редакторе можете райткликом на вкладке с логом назначить его в низ(Mowe to down) или куда удобно...

Comment: @Aeroua, спасибо, пожалуй, если не найдётся до окончания конкурса иного решения буду пользовать сдвинутую вниз вкладку с файлом логов. Не совсем то, но, по крайней мере, переоткрыть можно) Заодно завёл багу на сайте производителя IDE https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170540

Comment: Ну это скорее не баг а просто функционал которого нет. Для вкладок Редактора реализовано все, для вкладок Консоли нет опций и это связанно как мне объяснили со спецификой работы самих вкладок и передачей/отображением данных туда/там.

Answer (score 3):

Для наличия такой вкладки (с фильтрами и поиском по логам) нужно явно привязывать лог-файл к окружению сборки.

- Run/Debug configuration
- Logs
- +
- Введите алиас(имя вкладки) и полное имя файла логов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня так и сделано. Вопрос в том как вернуть эту вкладку main если её закрыть

Comment: Перезапуск не вариант? =)

Comment: Не очень вариант( Это лишние кнопки жать и ждать пока там всё скомпилится и задеплоится(

Comment: Я такой функции не нашёл. Возможно стоит писать JetBrains bugreport.

Comment: Эх... Ладно, попробую последнюю версию IDEA вечером поставить и напишу им в самом деле, если там не будет это поправлено(

Comment: Попробовал последнюю версию - всё то же самое( Придётся, видать, им идти жаловаться(

Comment: Ну, а что ещё делать? Само оно не починится. Другой вариант - забить и не закрывать вкладки)

Comment: В общем завёл у них багу. Посмотрим чего будет) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170540

Answer (score 1):

Правый нижний угол. Не он ли тебе нужен?

[image: правый нижний угол]

Comment: Не, там какие-то другие логи( Про процесс сборки и всё такое